# Drawing many spheres in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, performance, glut, visualization

I want to draw many spheres (~100k) using OpenGL. So far, I'm doing something like

```
for (int i=0; i<pnum; i++){
     glPushMatrix();
     glTranslatef(bpos[i].x, bpos[i].y, bpos[i].z);
     glCallList(DListSPHERE);
     glPopMatrix();
}
```

Before using proper spheres, I used `GL_POINTS`. That allowed me to call `glDrawArrays` with an array containing all points which was very efficient. Is there a better way than the above code to draw many, identical objects?

Comment: as Gregory Pakosz mentioned, instancing is the standard way to do that. However, I'm really not getting what real world case would require ~100K spheres. All things I can think of would be better served with round points. Care to shed some light on your use case ?

Comment: I simulate Saturn's rings and I want to visualise the results in real time. The visual feedback of "depth" is vital and therefore simple points don't work. See for example: http://hanno-rein.de/examplespheres.png and http://hanno-rein.de/examplepoints.png

Comment: Nice illustration. You can simulate the sphere look by doing the lighting in a pixel shader. Even just applying a basic texture would help you there already. Point being, 100K spheres is bound to hurt perf, while points wont as much (as you already noticed).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at this page on [instancing](http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/10/21/instancing/): it contains many references:

- Some test made that shows when to use instancing and when not: http://www.ozone3d.net/blogs/lab/?p=87
- An OpenGL implementation of a pseduo-instancing (recommended for old hardware).
  [glsl_pseudo_instancing.pdf](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/DEMOS/OpenGL/src/glsl_pseudo_instancing/docs/glsl_pseudo_instancing.pdf)
- OpenGL instancing:
  http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/draw_instanced.txt

See also [Geometry instancing on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_instancing).

Answer (score 3):

If you draw ~100k spheres, you might want to consider raycasting them instead of using polygon meshes to approximate them. The papers [GPU-Based Ray-Casting of Quadratic Surfaces](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/t.weyrich/projects/quadrics/pbg06.pdf)  by Sigg et al. (2006) and [Splatting Illuminated Ellipsoids with Depth Correction](http://www.inf.tu-dresden.de/content/institutes/smt/cg/publications/paper/ellipsoid.pdf) by Gumhold (2003) show how to do this. If you do this, you can reuse much of your fast point sprite code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use point sprites and a fragment shader to duplicate the effect of a rendered sphere without the actual sphere geometry.  I would try instancing first, however.