# Fast rotate and translate without using glRotate / glTranslate

Tags: opengl

I have an octagon which I need to rotate and translate to 10,000 different locations/angle. The angle and coordinates changes dynamically.

1. If I use glRotate and glTranslate in immediate mode, it would be too slow due to all the going back and forth between client/server.
2. If I use glRotate and glTranslate on a Display List, it will be fast, but I am avoiding Display List because it is deprecated.
3. If I use VBO, I have to pre-rotate and and pre-translate the octagon on the CPU prior to uploading it to server memory. This works, but takes lots of CPU time.

So I am wondering...is there anyway to translate/rotate  with vertices stored in VBO , without resorting to CPU based computation.  Is there a VBO equivalent for executing rotate/translate values stored in server memory? I would really love the GPU to do all the calculations and free my CPU from all the trig functions.

Comment: Oh man, I was going to present a clever answer but I totally forgot to bring an octagon!

Comment: Yes, my problem is that each translate/rotate command will work on a 8 vertice object (and not a 5000 vertices VBO per call) . This is not efficient way of doing things. The command lag will far outweight the render time.

Comment: Even *glRotate* and *glTranslate* are deprecated.

Comment: Yes, and I can see why they would deprecate it. At the speeds of today's GPU, with simple objects, it is often times faster to just do a CPU translate/rotate.  Does this mean, OpenGL expects all rotate/transformation be precomputed on CPU in the future or is there an alternate to glRotate/glTranslate ?

Comment: You're wrong: *glRotate*, *glTranslate* and all matrix functions are deprecated, but that is because the fixed pipeline is deprecated. You have to send your own matrix to your shader using *glUniformMatrix*. This has absolutely the same overhead as before!

Comment: Could you explain us how your locations/angles are computed by the application? There might be some way to compute the transforms on the GPU, but it's impossible to tell without knowing how your CPU compute the transforms.

Comment: glUniformMatrix - ok, something new for me to lookup on. Right now, I am pretranslating  (x+offset_x,y+offse_y) and prerotating (x' = cos(theta)*x - sin(theta)*y)  each vertex before uploading to VBO for rendering . This is done every single frame because it is dynamic (think of particles) .  If we can somehow upload 10,000 translate coordinate and 10,000 angles without making 10,000 gl calls, I think it can be done faster on the GPU.  Any pointers on where I should start looking ?

Comment: This might be a use case for geometry instancing (available in opengl as http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/draw_instanced.txt), see this answer for some further pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995262/drawing-many-spheres-in-opengl/1995266#1995266

Comment: Thank you Jorn - this was exactly what I was looking for! Will learn up on it.

Answer (score 3):

I would use VBO and regular `glRotate` and `glTranslate`, (or provide a matrix to a vertex shader using [glUniformMatrix](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml)). I don't think it will slow down the rendering!

Comment: It shouldn't slow it down, as long as you only set the matrices (projection & modelview) and do not modify the VBO-contents. The VBO should remain unchanged in the GPU-cards' memory, and you only feed it the matrices to do the translations with.

Comment: If a single glRoate/translate command works on 5000 vertices per call, then the overhead of calling this command may be negigible (eg you are only 20 sets objects). But if I try calling glRoate/translate  command that works on 8 vertices at a time, the overhead lag of going back and forth between CPU/GPU will be much greater than rendeing time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GLSL to write a shader that handles the transformation for you. However, you will need to make the transformation matrix available to the shader somehow.

If you are doing this in 2D, there's a similar question (for quads, but the theory is the same) on the game development stack exchange: [Basics of drawing in 2D with OpenGL 3 shaders](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25411/basics-of-drawing-in-2d-with-opengl-3-shaders).

Note that the second answer for that question, which gives more details, has a link to OpenGL.org which has a broken anchor. I believe it should link to [Instanced arrays](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Instanced_arrays).

An example of instancing I found after a quick google search: [Shader instancing](http://wiki.delphigl.com/index.php/shader_Instancing). In this tutorial you probably want to look at the vertex shader for an example of a transformation matrix applied using a texture buffer for storing the matrix. The example code is Delphi, but it should be readable. The site is in German, but you can always use Google translate.