# Efficiency of display lists in OpenGL with Python?

Tags: python, performance, opengl, pyopengl

I have been teaching myself OpenGL programming  using the Python wrapper PyOpenGL, and am now working on my first project with it. This project is a music visualizer (not dissimilar to whitecap) using many independently moving and independently colored cubes.

My current method is to have a display list for one cube and call it repeatedly changing color and location with glColor and glTranslatef like so (pseudocode):

```
glPushMatrix()
glPushMatrix() #Why do I need to call this twice?
for x in xrange(...):
    for z in xrange(...):
        y = height[x,z] #numpy array
        glTranslatef(x,y,z)
        glColor((r,g,b))
        glCallList(cube)
        glTranslatef(-x,-y,-z)
glPopMatrix()
glPopMatrix()
```

In this manner I can render about 10,000 cubes before I start to notice the framerate, this is OK but I would like it to be faster so my program is portable to less able computers, so my question is:

> **What would be the most efficient way to render many identical but
>   independent objects, and will I get much better performance than I am
>   now using display lists?**
>   Should I be using C or learning vertex
>   buffering?

Note: I found disabling the error checking gave a sizable performance boost.

Comment: Maybe this question could be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995262/drawing-many-spheres-in-opengl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like the common sense was wrong. You manually restore the transformation (`glTranslatef(-x,-y,-z)`) after drawing the `cube`, this way `glPopMatrix` is not only called twice for no reason, but it is also useless because you did all the work for it.
Correct code would like like so:

```
for x in xrange(...):
    for z in xrange(...):
        y = height[x,z] #numpy array
        glPushMatrix() #Remember the matrix
        glTranslatef(x,y,z) #change the matrix
        glColor((r,g,b))
        glCallList(cube)
        glPopMatrix() #Restore tha matrix as it was before glTranslate changed it
```

Comment: As for performance optimizations, please see the related topics here on SO.

Comment: Thank you, so judging from the other question the next step for performance may be **instancing**