# How do I draw a first person object using OpenGL

Tags: opengl

What I'm trying to do is draw a gun for a fps game I am making but it always seems to be off. I know I am supposed to draw it last with depth test disabled. But i just can't seem to get it to follow along with the view of the camera. Assume we are just drawing a triangle to represent the gun right now, with the base being at the players end. I have access to player position and the point where he is looking (used for gluLookAt) and I also have access pitch and yaw. And ideas on what to do?

Comment: What part of it would you like to see?

Comment: Enough to be able to know what it is you're currently doing. You've said what you want, and you've said that that's not what you're seeing. But you haven't said what you're currently doing that's causing what you're seeing.

Comment: when i try drawing the i translate to the player position and then rotate by the yaw, and then try to draw to gun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert but I would try something akin to the following for drawing the gun:

```
#If not already in modelview mode
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW) 

#Push the current modelview matrix onto the stack, leaving us working with a copy
glPushMatrix()

#Translate forward to where we want to draw the gun
glTranslatef(0,0,dist)

#Draw the gun starting from this position, translation may need to account for offset so that it is centered correctly
gun.draw() 

#Get rid of our modified modelview matrix and return to the original so that the camera is in the correct positon
glPopMatrix()
```

The best guide I have found for understanding OpenGL geometry is http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html

Good luck! :)

Comment: Why do you push/pop the matrix twice?

Comment: I have no idea but for some reason (at least in my very similar code) it doesn't work if you only do it once... Would be great if someone could explain! (It is in a question I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469034/efficiency-of-display-lists-in-opengl-with-python)